# Flow of momentum is pressure

Tags: general-relativity, pressure, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

In the diagonal terms of the [energy-momentum tensor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor), the flow of $x$-momentum in the $x$-direction is the $x$-pressure. Why the flow of momentum is pressure?

Comment: What you meant is actually named as "flux".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Consider some basic unit analysis. Pressure is defined as force/area which is the same as momentum/area/time since F=dp/dt. Momentum flow would be the momentum passing through a unit area per unit time so it's the same units. More physically, think of a gas at constant pressure in a box. If you popped a little hole of unit area in the side of the box, the pressure would be the amount of momentum escaping per unit time. Hope that helps!