# Would zero-energy tachyon fluid exert pressure?

Tags: general-relativity, fluid-dynamics, pressure, tachyon

Due to relativistic [energy momentum relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy%E2%80%93momentum_relation) a tachyon of mass $m_{0}$ and of zero energy poses momentum $p=m_{0}c$. Because [flow of momentum](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/38512) is pressure one can imagine that a spacetime filled with zero-energy tachyons has pressure, even without presence of normal matter.

My point is that there exists a valid static spherically symmetric perfect fluid solution of Einstein equations with zero energy density and non-zero pressure, see on that platform [The special case - Universe without matter but with pressure](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/679431/281096). The corresponding metric reads
$${\rm d}s^2=(1-p_{1}/4+p_{1}/4~r ^2/R^2)^2~c^2{\rm d}t^2-{\rm d}r^2-r^2{\rm d}\Omega^2~,\tag{1}$$
where $p_{1}\equiv p(R)~\kappa~R^2$ and $\kappa=8\pi G/c^4$, and the pressure and energy density are
$$p=p_{1}/(1-p_{1}/4+p_{1}/4~r^2/R^2),~~~~~~\varepsilon=0.\tag{2}$$
My question is whether one could interpret such a metric as spacetime filled with zero-energy tachyons?

Comment: Tachyonic matter is supposed to have a Type IV stress energy tensor according to Hawking-Ellis' classification (https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.00865). It remains to be checked whether stress energy tensor considered in this model is indeed Type IV

Comment: Yes, it was the assumption for that spacetime (Type IV).